There is no application set to open the URL about:srcdoc
I'm running macOS Sonoma on my MacBook Pro. Since I started work today, an error dialog appears about every 20 minutes with the message

There is no application set to open the URL about:srcdoc

How can I put a stop to this?


Hello! Might this computer be managed by a work IT that is trying to open some notification or help article? We might need more context to guess what you have going on that’s trying to get launchd to start an app to receive a file of that type.

@bmike yes it's a work laptop that has a variety of corporate software installed on it

That’s good, your team should be able to answer a call if this is malware or if they think it’s safe to open the document in text edit or a browser (via the choose application path out of that dialog…) to verify it’s something they sent and messed up slightly. Hopefully it’s not malware trying to get you to open a browser or run their payload.
